# How to define $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n,\mu)$ for a complex measure $\mu$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

For a positive measure $\mu$ we define the fuction space $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n,\mu)$ by 
$$L^p(\mathbb{R}^n,\mu)=\{f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C} |\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f|d\mu<\infty\}.$$
Similarly can we define $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n,\mu)$ for a complex measure $\mu$ using the fact that there exists a function $h, |h|=1$ such that $$d\mu=hd|\mu|$$ or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

$L^{p}(\mu)$ is the set of all (equivalence classes under $|\mu|$ of)  measurable  functions $f$ such that $\int |f|^{p} d|\mu| <\infty$. In other words there is no differenece between $L^{p}(\mu)$ and $L^{p}(|\mu|)$.

Comment: sir it will be very much helpful if you provide any references. I want to know how much it is standard.